# Javascript how to make 2 events onclick (getElementById and function)

Tags: javascript

I want the button onclick to change the photo from blank image (Vazio.jpg) to the one in jpg (RyukFigA300.jpg) which it does and to change the paragraph from Preco to Preço: R$250,00, I can't make the second one to work, text in < p > doesn't change, can anyone help me?

```
<th rowspan="6"><img id="imgproduto" class="imagemcatalogo" src="images/Vazio.jpg"><p id="precoproduto"> Preco </p>

<th><button onclick="document.getElementById('imgproduto').src='images/RyukFigA300.jpg'"; onclick="precoproduto6()">Ryouk em PVC</th>


<script language="javascript">

function precoproduto6(){
document.getElementById("precoproduto").innerHTML = 'Preço: R$250,00';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use semicolon to two thing on the click, try this

```
<th rowspan="6"><img id="imgproduto" class="imagemcatalogo" src="images/Vazio.jpg"><p id="precoproduto"> Preco </p>

<th><button onclick="document.getElementById('imgproduto').src='images/RyukFigA300.jpg';precoproduto6()">Ryouk em PVC</th>


<script language="javascript">

function precoproduto6(){
document.getElementById("precoproduto").innerHTML = 'Preço: R$250,00';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">

function precoproduto6(){
 document.getElementById('imgproduto').style.backgroundImage = "url('images/RyukFigA300.jpg')"
 document.getElementById("precoproduto").innerHTML = 'Preço: R$250,00';
}

<script/>
```